# Example of well-founded relation that is a proper class

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does anybody know of an example of a well-founded relation that is a proper class and is not a partial ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think of $\in$ on the universe of regular sets. It is a proper class and is not reflexive so is no partial order.